# Intuitive vs Formal (model-theoretic) definition of consistency of a theory

Tags: definition, first-order-logic, model-theory

A theory $T$ of $L$-sentences is said to be consistent if there exists a model of $T$. More precisely, there exists an $L$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ such that $M$ satisfies $\sigma$ for each $\sigma \in T$.

How does this definition of consistent compare with the more 'intuitive' definition of consistent, that is a theory $T$ is said to be consistent if and only if for all $L$-sentences $\sigma$, $T$ does not contain both $\sigma$ and $\lnot \sigma$. I think they should be equivalent but I am unable to come up with a proof.

I thought that if $T$ contains both, then any model of $T$ will satisfy both, so there cannot exist a model of $T$. But I am not sure how to show that there cannot exist a model of $T$.

Also, if $T$ is a consistent theory, then it has a model $\mathcal{M}$ and if there exists $\sigma, \lnot \sigma \in T$, then $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies both $\sigma$ and $\lnot \sigma$, which means $\mathcal{M}$ is not a valid $L$-structure. Again, I am not sure how to show that it is not a valid $L$-structure from the definitions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\sigma,\lnot \sigma \in T$.

A model of $T$ is a structure $\mathcal M$ such that:

> $\mathcal M \vDash T$.

Thus: $\mathcal M \vDash \sigma$ and $\mathcal M \vDash \lnot \sigma$.

But one of the clause of the definition of the *satisfaction* relation is:

> $\mathcal M \vDash \lnot \varphi \text {  if and only if it is not the case that  } \mathcal M \vDash \varphi$.

The usual terminology is: a theory $T$ is *satisfiable* iff it has a model.

Thus, the above argument is: if $T$ is inconsistent, then it is unsatisfiable, i.e. if $T$ is satisfiable, then is consistent. [*Thanks to David*.]

The other part of the equivalence: $T$ is *satisfiable* iff it is *consistent*, is the so-called [Model existence lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem#Model_existence_theorem), a more general version of Gödel's completeness theorem.

Comment: Thanks! Is my proof correct? I showed that if $T$ is consistent by the normal definition, then it is consistent by my 'new' definition, and if $T$ is not consistent by the new definition, then it is not consistent by the normal definition.

Comment: It's a good idea to have two words for the two conditions. No, your proof is not correct. You gave two proofs of the trivial direction "satisfiable implies consistent" and no proof that consistent implies satisfiable. That last is true, but it's not just an exercise; it's Godel's Completeness Theorem.'